# Avoid duplicate rows by keep same order in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for another solution for my sql query result.

My query below returns

```
SELECT 
    M.Mroutes_srno, M.Mroutes_loginid 
FROM
    Mroutes M
LEFT JOIN 
    MAccSanctioningLimit Limit ON M.mroutes_role = Limit.sac_type
                               AND M.Mroutes_moduleno = Limit.sac_moduleno
                               AND M.Mroutes_companycd = Limit.company_cd
WHERE
    M.mroutes_deptcd = 'BKAF'
    AND M.Mroutes_moduleno = 145
    AND M.mroutes_role NOT IN ('MIS', 'CFO', 'MD')
```

Output:

```
Mroutes_srno    Mroutes_loginid
--------------------------------
1   --------    AIJ1546
2   --------    BCS8021
3   --------    AIJ1546
4   --------    BCS8021
5   --------    venkatesh
6   --------    151N1636
```

But, after removing duplicate rows it result like below.

```
SELECT  
    M.Mroutes_loginid  
FROM
    Mroutes M
LEFT JOIN 
    MAccSanctioningLimit Limit ON M.mroutes_role = Limit.sac_type
                               AND M.Mroutes_moduleno = Limit.sac_moduleno
                               AND M.Mroutes_companycd = Limit.company_cd
WHERE 
    M.mroutes_deptcd = 'BKAF'
    AND M.Mroutes_moduleno = 145
    AND M.mroutes_role NOT IN ('MIS', 'CFO', 'MD')
GROUP BY
    M.Mroutes_loginid
```

Output:

```
Mroutes_loginid
---------------
151N1636
AIJ1546
BCS8021
venkatesh
```

I need to keep the query in same order.

Comment: Add an order by clause to your query. Something like "order by M.Mroutes_srno ASC".

Comment: It's not clear what is your question, or what you are trying to achieve.  You could use `order by Mroutes_loginid`, if what you want is a consistent order.

Comment: *I need to keep the query in same order.* - in that case, you must explicitly specify an `ORDER BY`  clause in your `SELECT`

Comment: yes right .. there is answer with order by min(M.Mroutes_srno)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `row_number` window function:

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT M.Mroutes_srno,
       M.Mroutes_loginid,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY M.Mroutes_loginid ORDER BY M.Mroutes_srno) rn 
from Mroutes M
left JOIN MAccSanctioningLimit  Limit on M.mroutes_role =Limit.sac_type
    and  M.Mroutes_moduleno = Limit.sac_moduleno
    and M.Mroutes_companycd = Limit.company_cd
where M.mroutes_deptcd ='BKAF'
and M.Mroutes_moduleno =145
and M.mroutes_role NOT in ('MIS', 'CFO', 'MD'))

SELECT Mroutes_srno, Mroutes_loginid
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Mroutes_srno
```

Or you can order by aggregation like:

```
SELECT  M.Mroutes_loginid  
from Mroutes M
left JOIN MAccSanctioningLimit  Limit on M.mroutes_role =Limit.sac_type
    and  M.Mroutes_moduleno = Limit.sac_moduleno
    and M.Mroutes_companycd = Limit.company_cd
where M.mroutes_deptcd ='BKAF'
and M.Mroutes_moduleno = 145
and M.mroutes_role NOT in ('MIS', 'CFO', 'MD')
group by M.Mroutes_loginid
order by min(M.Mroutes_srno)
```

Comment: thanks .. i used order by aggregation option its work

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because .. it might be possible that .. your delete query which deleting the duplicate record from  `Mroutes` table is deleting the first occurrence of `AIJ1546` values .. which leading `151N1636` to come first in result set ...

Try to skip the first occurrence row of duplicate value .. your probelm will be solved..

**Note:** When you did not specify any order by clause in select query it by-default choose the `primary key to sort the result set`..